# FormSet rendering always two forms as default Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following code for my FormSet:

## Forms.py

```
class RequiredFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RequiredFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
            form.empty_permitted = False

CityFormSet = formset_factory(CityNameForm, min_num=1, max_num=5, validate_min=True, validate_max=True, formset=RequiredFormSet)
```

## Template.html

```
{{ city_formset.management_form }}
{% for city_form in city_formset %}
{{ city_form.id }}
<div>
    {{ city_form.city_name }}
</div>

<div>
    {{ city_form.region }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Creating and deleting forms in the formset is handled by JavaScript, but it is only activated when a button is clicked. If the user edits the JavaScript and removes the condition where it verifies how many forms the page must have, he can submit the page without any form in the formset.

If I set `min_num=0` in the constructor, the user is able to use the scheme above and go over the validation. If I set it to `min_num=1`, he can't but two forms are generated within the formset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just change this line:

```
CityFormSet = formset_factory(CityNameForm, min_num=1, max_num=5, validate_min=True, validate_max=True, formset=RequiredFormSet)
```

to this:

```
CityFormSet = formset_factory(CityNameForm, min_num=1, max_num=5,
                              validate_min=True, validate_max=True,
                              formset=RequiredFormSet, extra=0)
```

Also made your line a bit shorter so you don't have to scroll so much.

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly it. If you ask me, that is a bit stupid to have it as 1 as default. It generates always two forms and you have no idea why. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe, but it's in the docs. Note that an empty form will be ignored if you submit. I think it exists so that it's obvious to the user that you can add more.

Answer (score 0):

in formset_factory has option with *extra*, you can utilize as extra=2